Why is the import of my external assets(3d model) not resolving even thought the path is correct?
I am trying to import a 3 D model to display on a canvas in my expo/react native application. The import is always unable to resolve and I am not sure why.
This is the entire application at this point.
import React, { Suspense, useRef } from 'react';
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Euler } from 'three';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';


const Shoe: React.FC = () => {
  const obj = useLoader(
    OBJLoader,
    require("./assets/models/AssetBundle/Airmax/shoe.obj")
  );
  return (
    <mesh rotation={[0.5, 0, 0]}>
      <primitive object={obj} scale={10} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Canvas>
        <ambientLight />
        <spotLight />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Shoe />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;

I have tried with 'require':
const obj = useLoader(
    OBJLoader,
    require("./assets/models/AssetBundle/Airmax/shoe.obj")
  );

and also with:
const obj = useLoader(
    OBJLoader,
    Asset.fromModule(require("./assets/models/AssetBundle/Airmax/shoe.obj")).uri
  );

To be honest, I have tried so many things
